# What does PowerISO mean by "unpacking" my image (*.img)?

Tags: boot, archiving, disk-image

I captured a bootable USB flash drive into an image (*.img) through PowerISO. When I open it in PowerISO, it indicates that it is in a sort of partitioning:

[image]

Then when I click on "Burn", this dialog box appears:

[image]

I suppose the img file serves as a wrapper for filesystem(s) within, but what does PowerISO mean in unpacking it first? Extracting the files within the img file with an archiving program such as 7z, Winrar, PowerISO itself, etc & use those files to create a file based compilation? Would the binaries meant for compliance with Legacy/UEFI/CSM be discarded then? If it needs El Torito of ISO 9660, how do I introduce it?

EDIT:
Tried my luck with MagicISO & no luck. Won't even open the captured img file. Help?

Comment: Why is nobody helping me?

Comment: https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/burn-img-file.htm https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)

Comment: img its sector by sector copy of device and you cant write it directly to optical disk because for optical data disc iso is needed

Comment: I used the Convert function in PowerISO to create an ISO. Still, I get the exact 2 dialog popping up.

Comment: I'm trying unpacking & building the ISO. Turns out it wasn't too hard.  Including the boot binaries, I've just learnt now.

Comment: _"Why is nobody helping me?"_ - your expectations may be a bit unrealistic? If you want an expert to immediately start solving your problem, maybe consider paid support. If you don't want to pay, that's understandable, but don't expect the same kind of service. This website is run by volunteers in their free time.

Comment: @TempusNomen - why not try to write an 'answer' to your own question, explain how you solved your problem - tell others how to do it.